# How to combine the @fixture and the @given decorators in Python hypothesis testing?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, hypothesis-test, python-hypothesis

I'm working with [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/) and [`hypothesis`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for property-based testing in Python.

As a minimal example, suppose I want to test that my `Matrix` class constructor correctly assign the number of rows and columns to a `Matrix` instance. I want to do it in two separate test functions but I also want them to share the same object to avoid recreating it twice (this can be done by using the [`pytest.fixture`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/how-to/fixtures.html) decorator).
However, at the same time, I want to use the [`hypothesis.given`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/details.html#hypothesis.given) decorator to make my test parameterized by an integer `seed` randomly generated by `hypothesis.strategies.integers`.

Is it possible to combine these two features? If not, is there any workaround to achieve this?

The code below is a minimal working example with my `test_nrows` and `test_ncols` functions sharing the same object created by the `matrix` fixture.

```
import numpy as np
from pytest import fixture

class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, nrows, ncols, seed=None):
        np.random.seed(seed)
        self.array = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols)

@fixture(scope='module')
def matrix():
    return Matrix(nrows=2, ncols=3)

def test_nrows(matrix):
    assert matrix.array.shape[0] == 2

def test_ncols(matrix):
    assert matrix.array.shape[1] == 3
```

I want to make the tests parameterized rewriting the fixture function as something like the following:

```
from hypothesis import given, strategies

@given(seed=strategies.integers())
@fixture(scope='module')
def matrix(seed):
    return Matrix(nrows=2, ncols=3, seed=seed)
```

However, this fails with the error message `fixture 'matrix' not found`.

Comment: Does it work if you reverse the order of the decorators?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't but it gives a different error: `Can't apply @pytest.fixture() to matrix because it is already decorated with @hypothesis.given()`

Answer (score 3):

You're not supposed to combine `@hypothesis.given` and `@pytest.fixture` like that. The way to implement random matrix draws is by defining your own [composite strategy](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#composite-strategies), not a fixture.

Let's say this was your `Matrix` class, as in your example,

```py
import typing as tp

import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
    

class Matrix:

    array: npt.NDArray[np.float_]

    def __init__(self, nrows: int, ncols: int, seed: int) -> None:
        np.random.seed(seed)
        self.array = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols)
```

then your composite hypothesis search strategy would be defined as follows:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing as tp

import hypothesis.strategies as st
import numpy as np


if tp.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import numpy.typing as npt
    from hypothesis.strategies import SearchStrategy


seed_strategy: tp.Final[SearchStrategy[int]] = st.integers(
    # Bounds given are for the acceptable range of `numpy.random.seed`
    min_value=0, max_value=2**32 - 1
)


@st.composite
def drawMatrix(
    drawFromStrategy: st.DrawFn, /, *, nrows: int = 2, ncols: int = 3
) -> Matrix:

    """
    Strategy which draws random `numpy.float_` matrices of dimensions (nrows × ncols)

    Parameters
    ----------
    drawFromStrategy
        Callable which draws items from other hypothesis search strategies
    nrows
        Number of rows for the matrix
    ncols
        Number of columns for the matrix

    Returns
    -------
    Matrix
        Matrix for testing
    """

    seed: int = drawFromStrategy(seed_strategy)
    return Matrix(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, seed=seed)
```

Your pytest tests would then be written as the following:

```py
_2x3_matrix_strategy: tp.Final[SearchStrategy[Matrix]] = drawMatrix()


@hypothesis.given(matrix=_2x3_matrix_strategy)
def test_nrows(matrix: Matrix) -> None:
    assert matrix.array.shape[0] == 2


@hypothesis.given(matrix=_2x3_matrix_strategy)
def test_ncols(matrix: Matrix) -> None:
    assert matrix.array.shape[1] == 3


@hypothesis.given(matrix=drawMatrix(nrows=3, ncols=4))
def test_bad_dimensions(matrix: Matrix) -> None:
    assert matrix.array.shape[0] == 2
    assert matrix.array.shape[1] == 3
```

Demonstration of this in action:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.10.5, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: ..., configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: hypothesis-6.54.5, anyio-3.6.2
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

test_matrix.py ..F                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  [100%]

=============================================================================================================================== FAILURES ================================================================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_bad_dimensions __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

    @hypothesis.given(matrix=drawMatrix(nrows=3, ncols=4))
>   def test_bad_dimensions(matrix: Matrix) -> None:

test_matrix.py:91: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

matrix = <test_matrix.Matrix object at 0x7f1dfb263d90>

    @hypothesis.given(matrix=drawMatrix(nrows=3, ncols=4))
    def test_bad_dimensions(matrix: Matrix) -> None:
>       assert matrix.array.shape[0] == 2
E       assert 3 == 2
E       Falsifying example: test_bad_dimensions(
E           matrix=<test_matrix.Matrix at 0x7f1dfb263d90>,
E       )

test_matrix.py:92: AssertionError
======================================================================================================================== short test summary info ========================================================================================================================
FAILED test_matrix.py::test_bad_dimensions - assert 3 == 2
====================================================================================================================== 1 failed, 2 passed in 0.46s ======================================================================================================================
```

---

Please see the [source code](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/blob/70b713a546e012685160e4cc27868b2aa2442c2d/hypothesis-python/src/hypothesis/strategies/_internal/core.py#L1590-L1605) for the signature expected of the function decorated by `@st.composite`. In short, the first parameter **must** take a positional argument which indicates the hypothesis drawing function. This parameter is "swallowed" when you decorate this with `@st.composite` to make strategy factory callables (kind of like how `self` is "swallowed" when calling instance methods).